# Core Data: Correct way to update within a NSUrlRequest

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I have a NSUrlRequest in which i call a method `User.updateMyObject(id: NSNumber, name: String)`. Object `User` has the static properties:

```
static let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
static let MOC = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
```

And several methods for updating/creating/deleting objects.

Now, I have read that you shouldn't use you `MOC` on different threads. And as far as I know a NSUrlRequest runs asynchronously. How would I then go about calling `MyObject.updateMyObject(id: NSNumber, name: String)`?

I sometimes get the error:

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil with userInfo (null)
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFSet addObject:]: attempt to insert nil'
```

My request looks like this:

```
let session = URLSession.shared
    // The singleton shared session is for basic requests.
    // Data tasks send and receive data using NSData objects.
    // Data tasks are intended for short, often interactive requests to a server.
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) {
        (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in

    //JSon parsing
    MyObject.updateMyObject(id: NSNumber, name: String)
} 
task.resume()
```

`MyObject.updateMyObject(id: NSNumber, name: String)` looks like this:

```
static func updateMyObject(id: NSNumber, name: String) {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MyObject")
    let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "id = \(id)")
    request.predicate = resultPredicate

    do {
        let result = try User.MOC.fetch(request).first as! MyObject

        result.name = name

        User.appDelegate.saveContext()
    }
    catch {
        print("User.updateMyObject: error.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is why the `perform` and `performAndWait` methods exist on `NSManagedObjectContext`-- so that you can safely use the context on different threads. You should use one of them here.

In general, any time you touch anything Core Data related, you need to wrap that code in a call to one of these two methods. The methods take a closure as an argument; put your Core Data code in that closure. The only exception to this rule, ever, is if you used `mainQueueConcurrencyType` **and** you know that your code is running on the main queue.

Comment: Hi Tom thanks for the answer, much appreciated. Could you come with an example? I'm not sure if I should add it inside the JSON parsing part of the request or somewhere else?

Comment: @FrederikNorlykEriksen more detail added